# Simulate a simple multipath channel for OFDM Modulation test. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ofdm, multipath

Hi I need to simulate a simple multipath channel in matlab through which I can send my OFDM transmission signal, I want to test my OFDM receiver design.
So far I have:

```
%% Passing through Channel
nIFFT = 4096;

% Create channel
channel = randn(1,nIFFT) + sqrt(-1)*randn(1,nIFFT);

% cext_data is the signal to be transmitted
after_channel = filter(channel, 1, cext_data); 
wavwrite(after_channel,'ofdm_tx8khz.wav');
```

I get a warning when I run the transmitter:

> Warning: Data clipped during write to file:ofdm_tx8khz.wav

and when I run the receiver I get:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in ofdm_rx (line 26)
>
> chunk2 = signal((s+nIFFT):(s+nIFFT+nCyclic-1));

I was really hoping someone could help me simulate a multipath channel for my OFDM program.

Comment: Personally I don't like when people are using `sqrt(-1)` for imaginary unit. First of all MATLAB has in-built variables: `i`, (`1i`), `j`. Secondly, from mathematical point of view solution for $\sqrt{-1}$ is both: $i$ and $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Wav files expect values from -1 to +1.  You are probably exceeding those limits when you filter the signal through the channel model.  After the channel filter add the following:

`after_channel = after_channel / max(abs(after_channel));`

I suspect, though, that you will still have a problem.  I believe that wavwrite ignores the imaginary part of complex data, so you will be losing that part of the signal.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I did try that and the error persists. What should I do?
Is there any other way I could simulate a simple multipath channel for my program ?

Comment: Then normalize it: `after_channel_norm = after_channel ./ max(abs(after_channel))`

Comment: @Deve Good call.  Modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, that did solve the data being clipped error however I am still getting the second error during the reception of the signal.
The line with the error is in my cross-correlation i have made a number of changes but it still is giving the same error, here's the fucntion: 


http://codetidy.com/4165/

Comment: @user8572 Questions about programming problems should really go to StackOverflow, not Signal Processing.

Comment: the only reason i have posted the code above is because it is a part of my previous query, is there anyway I could be helped on this?

Comment: Hi I have tried posting there as well, I haven't had much luck, I would be really obliged if someone here could help me out ?

Comment: Could you explain why do we need to normalize the received signal as below? after_channel_norm = after_channel ./ max(abs(after_channel))

Comment: @tuner It makes sure that all of the signal values are between -1 and 1.  The maximum value will be 1, and the others will be less than that.

Comment: So it is not an optional step at RX, rigtht? As we are trying to get the originaly transmitted data from TX, which is the data generated by TX between +/-1.